# How to make uniqueness validator ignore header and not ignore text case, in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a data validator which is like this:

```
=COUNTIF($D:$D,"="&D1) < 2
```

[image]

Notice that `meaning` is invalid. That is only because it appears in the header. Also, notice this:

[image]

It doesn't ignore case. How do I both ignore case and have it ignore the header when validating uniqueness of the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Header Exclusion

Exclude the header by...  ...excluding it from your range:

```
replace: $D:$D

with:    $D$2:$D
```

#### Respect Case

Respect case by using EXACT (case sensitive) in SUMPRODUCT instead of COUNTIF:

```
replace:  =COUNTIF($D:$D,"="&D1) < 2

with:     =SUMPRODUCT(EXACT($D2,$D$2:$D))<2
```